# Hide an inline style using angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to hide only the inline style(`style="float:left;"` from `ul` tag) when `data.unlock_scode` value is present. `ng-show="data.unlock_scode"` is working fine in `img` tag and I can't use the same in `ul` tag then it will hide the entire `ul` section.

```
<ul style="float:left;">
   <li ng-show="data.upfront != ''">Test</li>
</ul>
<img src="u70007.jpg" ng-show="data.unlock_scode" style="float:left;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-style

```
<ul ng-style="!data.unlock_scode" style="float:left;">
  .....
</ul>
```

better way is not to add inline style instead use ng-class

```
.someclass{
    add css here..
}

.someotherclass{
   add css here..
}    

ng-class="{someclass: !data.unlock_scode, someotherclass: data.unlock_scode}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-style` to have condition on your styles

```
<ul ng-style="{'float': data.unlock_scode ? 'inherit':'left'}">
   <li ng-show="data.upfront != ''">Test</li>
</ul>
```